# Scheduler is not working

Tags: php, iis-7, codeigniter-2

I set a scheduler in IIS7, I give the path to php and my URL to run as argument.

The PHP path is `C:\php\php.exe` and the argument is `-C:\domain.com\usage\index.php`.
The site is working with CodeIgniter, and the application folder path and the controller name and function to be called is set in `index.php`.

But when running the scheduler, I cannot get the output. I tried to echo test value before the controller class is loaded, I got the value but after that I cannot get anything and scheduler process is exit.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter (and other php frameworks) working with a router. So, you can not run index.php without "Controller/Action/Parameters" request.

the best way to call CI controller from command line is :

```
C:\php\php.exe -C:\domain.com\usage\index.php controller action
```

please read more from : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

Comment: i set the controller name and the function to be called  in the router
 like this
$application_folder = '../../httpdocs/v3/application';
 
 $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = '/usage/institute_usage';
$_GET = ''; 

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/usage/institute_usage';

Comment: did you try run this code without waiting scheduler time and see output?

Comment: i tried to run this scheduler , command prompt just open and close.
And i tried to print a numaric test loop before the controller is starting then i got the value .But i tried to print a numaric loop in that function i canot get it.

Comment: run this command in a .bat file and wirte PAUSE to end of file. see the output.

Comment: in the controller i added a function to update the daily usage of the site, in .bat file what i needed to add.

Comment: add the commant which I wrote in my answer and then add "PUASE" after that line. run it once and post here the output.

Comment: i resolved that  issue, issue due to scheduler settings.In scheduler, Action setting i inputed the php exe path but it is notworking. i changed that program/script to **'php'**.Then its work well.
Thank you for your support.

Comment: I resolved the issue by changing Action/Script 'C:\php\php.exe' to *php* in Scheduler settings.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the path to php.exe  in the scheduler settings.I resolved the issue by changing 'C:\php\php.exe' to 'php' .Then it is working.